# Converting F# Quotations into LINQ Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, f#, quotations

I can convert a quotation of type `Expr<'a -> 'b>` to a Linq expression via the following snippet:

```
/// Converts a F# Expression to a LINQ Lambda
let toLambda (exp:Expr) =
    let linq = exp.ToLinqExpression() :?> MethodCallExpression
    linq.Arguments.[0] :?> LambdaExpression

/// Converts a Lambda quotation into a Linq Lamba Expression with 1 parameter
let ToLinq (exp : Expr<'a -> 'b>) =
    let lambda = toLambda exp
    Expression.Lambda<Func<'a, 'b>>(lambda.Body, lambda.Parameters)
```

Now I want to convert a quotation of type `Expr<'a * 'b -> 'c>` or maybe even `Expr<'a -> 'b -> 'c>` to a Linq Lambda Expression of type `Expression<Func<'a,'b'c>>`.

How can I do this?

Regards,
  forki

Comment: where is the method `ToLinqExpression()` defined? I can't seem to find it

Comment: `expr.ToLinqExpression()` is now in `F#` as `Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression expr`

Comment: To clarify: This is available as of F# 3.0; given the date of the original question, probably even 2.0 already.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is directly supported by the LINQ modules available in the F# PowerPack. However, you can implement your own post-processing of the LINQ expression produced by F# libraries to turn it into a C# lambda function of the usual form:

The following function takes a LINQ expression which is constructed as multiple nested `LambdaExpression` expressions of a single parameter (that is, the structure produced by F# translator) and returns a list of parameters and body of the inner-most expression:

```
let rec translateExpr (linq:Expression) = 
  match linq with
  | :? MethodCallExpression as mc ->
      let le = mc.Arguments.[0] :?> LambdaExpression
      let args, body = translateExpr le.Body
      le.Parameters.[0] :: args, body
  | _ -> [], linq
```

Now you can use it to get an ordinary `Func` delegate out of type such as `int -> int -> int -> int` like this:

```
let linq = (<@@ fun a b c -> (a + b) * c @@>).ToLinqExpression()
let args, body = translateExpr liq
let f = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int, int, int>>
          (body, args |> Array.ofSeq)
f.Compile().Invoke(10, 11, 2)
```

Comment: `(<@@ fun a b c -> (a + b) * c @@>).ToLinqExpression()` is now in `F#` as `Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers.LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression (<@@ fun a b c -> (a + b) * c @@>)`